# What can be done about an unsafe/outdated gem dependency of a required gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler

I have bundler-audit (a check for known vulnerable gems) included as a pre-commit and in CI. It comes up with a known vulnerability in a previous version of the `nokogiri` gem and recommends I upgrade.

But here's the rub: the vulnerable gem is among the transitive dependencies of Rails and a few other gems I can't strip out. Some of them use a pessimistic version specifier which explicitly precludes the version of nokogiri to which I'd need to upgrade.

What does one do in a situation like this? Any advice?

Comment: Fork the gem, update its dependencies and open a pull request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the current Rails 4.x gem has this dependency, file a bug against Rails.

I'd be very surprised if the current 4.x version of Rails has a dependency on an insecure version of a gem, though.

Comment: Duh. Wow. Somebody's been outside of open source for too long... Thanks!